# What can we say about the dim(img(A)) in the terms of eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that symmetric matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues. Can we say that the number of lin. independent eigenvectors equals to dimension of the image (rank)?

Comment: What if one of the eigenvalues is zero?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot.  What we can say is that the rank is equal to the number of linearly independent eigenvectors *that are associated with non-zero eigenvalues*.